# How import data to Oracle with PowerQuery

Tags: oracle, odbc, powerquery

I usually connect Oracle with Excel via PowerQuery. For example, I download in Excel my Oracle SERVER.TABLE doing the following: = Odbc.Query("dsn=SERVER", "SELECT * FROM TABLE;").

Now I want to do the opposite. Now I have some data in Excel and I want to create a new table in Oracle. In other words, I want to import my Excel file to SERVER.TABLE_NEW.

How can I do this using PowerQuery? Thank you for advanced.

I tried to modify this line Odbc.Query("dsn=SERVER", "SELECT * FROM TABLE;"). But I didn't succeed.

Comment: you cannot export from powerquery.  You would have to output from powerquery, then input powerquery output to Oracle

Comment: Please, can you tell me more details. I want to do something like that: 
Odbc.Query("dsn=SERVER", "CREATE TABLE TABLE_NEW AS SELECT * FROM xxxxxx;"), where xxxxxx is my Excel data. 

I don't know how to code it properly. Thank you.

Comment: Can you give me more details about how to input to Oracle my powerquery output? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ODBC, but you'll be better off using the power-query editor UI to connect to your Oracle database using Oracle-specific methods. It will be more performant.

Power Query does not export. Period.

However, it **can** execute SQL statements!

So, you've got the major piece of it already. In your case, something like

```ml
let
  SQL = "INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3)
VALUES
  (1, 11, 'apple'),
  (2, 22, 'banana');”,
  #"Executed SQL" = Odbc.Query("dsn=SERVER", SQL)
in
  #"Executed SQL"
```

So now the problem is simply setting that `SQL` variable to the right string.

If you had a table query called MyTable, then you could make a second query called MyTableSQL that you can use instead of a hardcoded SQL string, something like

```ml
let
  SQL1 = "INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3)
VALUES",
  SQL2 = Text.Combine(
    Table.TransformRows(
      MyTable,
      each Text.Combine(
        {
          "  (",
          Text.From([Column1]),
          ", ",
          Text.From([Column2]),
          ", '",
          [Column3],
          "')"
        }
      )
    ),
    ",#(lf)" // line feed char
  ),
  SQL = Text.Combine(
    {
      SQL1,
      SQL2
    },
    "#(lf)"
  )
in
  SQL
```